# SharePoint Online - Content Search based on page 'Wiki Category' field

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part, search-query

I have added a Content Search web part to a Wiki Page Layout and I want to display all Wiki Pages that have the same category as the page the user is on.

My plan is to use the page field "Wiki Category" as part of the query string (eventually I will create sections based on other fields and to have documents tagged as well) but I can't work out the correct syntax / identifier for the page field name, "Wiki Categories".

I have been using this [Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj683123.aspx)

I have a category called "CRM" and when I use the following KQL:

```
path:"https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/ITIS-Wiki" WikiCategory:"CRM"
```

(this works and returns the pages)

[image]

```
path:"https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/ITIS-Wiki"   WikiCategory:{Page.Wiki%20Category}
```

(this doesn't work and returns nothing)

[image]

I have tried different variations of "Wiki Category" such as:

- Wiki Categories
- Wiki Category
- Category
- Categories
- Wiki%20Category
- Wiki%20Categories
- \Page.ones above

Just in case its called something else, but with no success. Does anyone know what would work?

Comment: can you try it as `WikiCategory:{Page.WikiCategory}` ?

Comment: Thanks Sheth, I've just tried that but it didn't work :(